# Laplacian in rectangular coordinates when polar is natural

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, polar-coordinates

This may seem like a strange question, but I am interested in solving $$\nabla^2 u = 0, \, r > R$$
with $u \to Ur \cos \theta$ for $r \to \infty$ and $\frac{\partial u}{\partial r} \big |_{r=R} = 0$. The solution in polar coordinates is easily found to be
$$ u(r,\theta) = U \cos \theta \left(r + \frac{R^2}{r} \right). $$
Correspondingly, one can then go to rectangular coordinates to obtain
$$u(x,y) = U x \left( 1 + \frac{R^2}{x^2+y^2} \right),$$
via substitution.

My question is does someone know of a way to solve this in rectangular coordinates first? I attempted separation of variables but the closest I can come to a solution is
$$u(x,y) = Ux + \sum_{\lambda > 0} e^{-\lambda |x|} [A_\lambda \sin(\lambda y) + B_\lambda \cos(\lambda y)],$$
which is not at all obvious how it will get to the correct form above. Does anyone have any suggestions?

**EDIT:** The comments correctly suggested I should have $\lambda$ run over all possible values, so I have changed the above series to now be

$$u(x,y) = Ux + \sum_{\lambda > 0} e^{-\lambda |x|} [A_\lambda \sin(\lambda y) + B_\lambda \cos(\lambda y)] + \sum_{\lambda < 0} e^{\lambda |y|} [C_\lambda \sin(\lambda x) + D_\lambda \cos(\lambda x)]$$

Comment: If you want to focus on the summation, it may be sensible to introduce $v(x,y)\equiv u(x,y)-Ux$. This will satisfy Laplace's equation but now with the boundary conditions $v\to 0$ at infinity and $(\partial v/\partial r)_{r=R}=- U\cos(\theta)$. The first condition is explicitly satisfied; for the second, it seems like one should translate it into Cartesian coordinates. So that may be a thread to pull.

Comment: This is not a strange question at all! You're solving for the electrostatic potential around a conducting cylinder placed in a background uniform electric field. Your solution is a superposition of the potential from the background field $Ux$ plus a contribution from an electric dipole $UR^2 x / r^2$ (due to the polarisation of the conducting cylinder).

Comment: The sum over $\lambda$ bothers me - (i) we would have a sum over infinitely many $\lambda$'s, like in a Fourier transform, and (ii) this sum is breaking the rotational symmetry.

Comment: Hint:  $x= r \cos(\theta)$ and $y = r \sin(\theta)$, then impose boundary condition.

Comment: @HR-Physics Could you please explain? Your hint is a bit cryptic. :) I believe the original question is whether this problem can be solved from scratch, using separation of variables in Cartesian coordinates.

Comment: @KennyWong Well, the boundary conditions break the symmetry. (There's some definite direction to the external electric field in the electrostatic context.) That said, it does seem nontrivial that the sum would simplify so much.

Comment: @Semiclassical Good point. The $UR^2 x / r^2$ contribution (coming from the induced dipole moment of the conducting cylinder) decays in all directions; it just decays faster in the $y$ direction than in the $x$ direction. Perhaps there is a way to write a "wavepacket" (i.e. a linear combination of the $e^{i\lambda y} e^{-|\lambda |x}$ over a continuous range of real $\lambda$) that reproduces the desired solution? Or perhaps we have to allow $\lambda$ to be imaginary? I'm not sure...

Comment: All good suggestions. Thanks for thinking about it. I will try some of these and see if they lead anywhere.

Comment: Just an update to all interested, have not made much headway. Though it seems like one should be able to get this solution, I feel like it may not be at all simple, the only reason why it feels doable is how simple the solution looks. Though I fear this may be misleading...